# Woocommerce Product Unable to delet from Cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After updating woocommerce to 3.6.2, once added i can not remove a product from cart.Intially it's showing rtemoved but again it's coming back when refresh the page.I am not using any caching plugin aslo i tried deactivate all plugins as well changing the theme, but no result.
When i am trying remove cart the following ajax is called:

```
http://www.domainname.com/cart/?removed_item=1
```

Immediately there is another ajax call which again bring the image back and not removing from the cart

```
http://www.domainname.com/cart/?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the cloud-flair caching.Once removed the IP from Cloudflare, the cart stated working as normal.